# How to cast lambdas?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, casting, lambda

I'd like a family of functions to be kept in a dictionary that derive from some base type (lets call the base class "object" for example sake). So, it it possible to keep f1 in f2?

```
Func<bool> f1 = () => true;
Func<object> f2 = f1;
```

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Func<bool>` to `System.Func<object>`

Is this the best we can do?

```
Func<bool> f1 = () => true;
Func<object> f2 = () => (object)f1;
```

Errors: (none)

I guess what it needs to be generic friendly is a where statement... but I'm not sure if you can do that with lamdas.

---

Following up on Armen's info, I dug into the definitions of string and bool:

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IEnumerable,
                             IComparable<String>, IEnumerabl<char>,
                             IEquatable<String> 

public struct Boolean : IComparable, IConvertible, IComparable<Boolean>,
                        IEquatable<Boolean>
```

He's right about ref Vs value.  Does String derive from object implicitly?  Looks like that is the behaviour for structs according to @PeterK's link.

> "ValueType overrides the virtual methods from Object with more
>   appropriate implementations for value types. See also Enum, which
>   inherits from ValueType."

Object:

> System.Object: All classes, structures, enumerations, and delegates.
>   (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object)

Which in turn makes `Func<bool>` not being assignable to `Func<object>` a little bit dumb.  i.e. the inheritance hierarchy was correct from that point of view.

Comment: All of your f1 type functions could be `Func<dynamic>`

Comment: `Func<object> f2 = () => (object)f1;` should be `Func<object> f2 = () => (object)f1();`

Comment: @leppie: but the value is boxed then so you'd expect that.  I appreciate the work arounds.  I'm just trying to align my mental model of how it should work with how it actually works.  I know .net will win here, but I'm talking in an ideal world.  It's a pretty minor point.  Maybe there's a compiler implementation detail that gets in the way of the language... or maybe it is just me who is at fault here.

Comment: @sgtz: `(object)f1` just returns the delegate, and you never call it it.

Comment: @leppie: did you dig into MSIL to know that?

Comment: @sgtz: no, it is bloody obvious...

Comment: @leppie: sometimes you hear about the language team struggling to implement constructs on top of the CLR.  It's those kinds of pure Vs we did this approximation type thing that I was interested in.  btw: I checked your web site, and it appears that you aren't shy at doing a little reverse engineering / digging into core dumps.  Not everyone has that depth (readers please say otherwise if I'm wrong).  In any case, what the compiler does is not completely on topic as I'm trying to appreciate C# as a language designer at the moment.  ty.

Comment: @sgtz: Did you even run the code you suggest? Did you call `f2().GetType()` to see that in fact that you did NOT have a `bool` like you say you have, but in fact a `Func<bool>`.

Comment: @leppie: how is it that this is conducive to community?  What are you aiming at?  The answer to your question is yes, there are test cases.  I'm happy to reword the question to reflect any perceived omissions.  I do appreciate your comments, but not the sharp edge to your wit. Stating "self evident" is normally what a professor might do.  Back off a bit 'eh?  Some of us would like to stay curious.

Comment: @leppie: since you authored http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/, you'd think that you would be a good person to discuss a nuance like this with. Maybe you are too close to the .net internals.

Comment: @sgtz: I was trying to point out a possible typo from your side, but it seems you do not quite want to understand what I am trying to tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter. This allows for implicit conversion of classes that implement variant interfaces and implicit conversion of delegate types. Covariance and contravariance are supported for reference types, **but they are not supported for value types**.

[Also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

The reason *might* have to do with how C# and the CLI historically deal (and don't agree) with array covariance of value types. Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx) for some info.

So you see, the covariance of the type parameter in `Func<out TResult>` doesn't work with value types, so you have to do this:

```
Func<object> f2 = () => f1();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 4.0+, this is possible.

Your example doesn't work because bool is a value type. If you were to change bool with string, however, the sample works.

```
    Func<string> f1 = () => "true";
    Func<object> f2 = f1;
```

Comment: @PeterK. [Wrong. They totally do.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype)

Comment: +1 a bit weird that structs derive from ValueType which then derive from object though.  Just trying to think that one through.  Thanks for clarifying.